# COM Elevation Moniker

Tags: delphi, uac, elevation, moniker

**Greetings!**

Wondered about creating COM ActiveX module to the program, which will be called if necessary with elevated privileges.

To do all this using Delphi XE5 and Windows 8.1 Pro x64.

Made ActiveX Library, added COM Object, added a test function. Registered in the system, using the Run> ActiveX Server-> Register.
The operation was successful.

Here are my library has a GUID:

```
  LIBID_libCOM: TGUID = '{B6D13396-71C2-4503-B314-65E72F176413}';
  IID_ITestOBJ: TGUID = '{0FD34325-6654-4DC4-9537-11CAA5B25652}';
  CLASS_TestOBJ: TGUID = '{1FDCEE9D-E747-4616-9D00-D55D7FD26B03}';
```

Object interface:

```
  ITestOBJ = interface (IUnknown)
    ['{0FD34325-6654-4DC4-9537-11CAA5B25652}']
    function GetSum (S1: HResult; S2: HResult): HResult; stdcall;
  end;
```

If you call in the usual way, then it works:

```
var
 II, TOBJ: ITestOBJ;
begin
 II: = CoTestOBJ.Create;
 II.QueryInterface (ITestOBJ, TOBJ);
ShowMessage (IntToStr (TOBJ.GetSum (StrToInt (Edit1.Text), StrToInt (Edit2.Text))));
end;
```

After that I added to the registry LocalisedString, Elevation \ Enabled, Elevation \ IconReference

Next, call the code:

```
var
 z: ITestOBJ;
 hr: HRESULT;

 BO: BIND_OPTS3;
 MonikerName: WideString;
begin
 hr: = 0;
 z: = nil;

 MonikerName: = 'Elevation: Administrator! New:' + GUIDToString (CLASS_TestOBJ);
 FillChar (BO, SizeOf (BIND_OPTS3), 0);

 BO.cbStruct: = SizeOf (BIND_OPTS3);
 BO.dwClassContext: = CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER;
 BO.hwnd: = Self.Handle;

 hr: = CoGetObject (PWideChar (MonikerName), @ BO, ITestOBJ, @ z);



 OleCheck (hr);

 ShowMessage (IntToStr (z.GetSum (1, 2)));
end;
```

Request comes from UAC to provide law, I click Yes.

After that, an error "Class not registered".

What am I doing wrong? After all, almost all figured out, is likely to remain small detail!

**P.S.**

In general, it is possible to call a COM object from a DLL library without registering it in the system and request elevation?
So it was much easier to LN, and would automatically solve some kind of other problem.

Comment: Where is the class registered? Under HKLM?

Comment: Are you aware about [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/282747/en-us)?

Comment: In general, you *can* load a COM object from a DLL without registering it - use `LoadLibrary()` and `GetProcAddress()` to access the DLL's `DllGetClassObject()` function directly. But if UAC Elevation is needed then the DLL *must* be registered in order for the Elevation Moniker to find it.

Comment: And make sure when you register the DLL that you are running elevated to begin with (run the IDE as an admin), or else the DLL registration may be virtualized to a different section of the Registry, which would explain why the Moniker cannot find it.

Comment: If you do not run the IDE from an administrator, you generally will not check in - error) So now run the IDE always elevated.

Comment: "without registering it in the system and request elevation?". No, otherwise it would allow to bypass the very reason of elevation.